# mongoose: findOne based on specific field in Object from nested array of ObjectIds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently have a database structure (pseudocode) like:

```
SchemaA = {
    name: String
}
SchemaB = {
    ARR: [{type: ObjectId, ref: "SchemaA"}]
}
```

Is there a way to query the object ids in SchemaB's ARR array for a specific name?
Something like

```
SchemaB.findOne({ "ARR.name": "exampleName" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use populate in mongoose to get object from objectId, after that you can find a one you want. You can read more about populate [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) with example.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it in one step? With populate I would have to pull then filter.

Comment: until pull everyone is unaware of what data it have using id itself.

Comment: The [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#database-references) type is used by drivers and clients.  If you want to query on the server side using aggregation, just store an ObjectID that is not a DBref, and use $lookup.